# Node module is not able to import

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tableau-api, npm-install

I'm using nodejs third party module in my project. I followed the document given in NPM site. But when i execute js script using node,its showing error node module not found.

- My node-module [tableau-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tableau-api) 
  My code :
- lambda function for alexa skill

  ```
  'use strict';
  const Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
  var tab = require("tableau-api");

  exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
      const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
      alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
      alexa.execute();
  };

  const handlers = {
      'LaunchRequest': function() {
          this.emit('SayHello');
      },
      'HelloWorldIntent': function() {
          this.emit('SayHello');
      }
  };
  ```

Error:

```
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'tableau-api'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:3:11)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"
```

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: Please make sure you has install this package successfully(check if there is **tableau-api** directory in the **node_modules**.

Comment: yes @KevinLaw its existing. please check the link given above. But its not loading.

Comment: Run `npm remove -S tableau-api` and then `npm install -S tableau-api`

Comment: did you tried direct import like `import tableau from "tableau-api";`

Comment: Go to your package.json and make sure it has been installed in your dependencies

Comment: Yes @RICKYKUMAR, getting unexpected token import

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you have not installed the package.

Try npm install --save tableau-api

Comment: I tried already, getting installed successfully. But cant use require